# Java previous button cycle

Tags: java, arrays, swing, button, cycle

I am trying to create previous and next buttons in addition to my first and last buttons. I have managed to get them all to work. However, I cannot seem to get the previous and next buttons to cycle through the array and instead I get errors when reaching the end. I'm not even sure where to start, but all help is very much appreciated!

```
    JButton firstButton = new JButton("First");
    buttonPanel.add(firstButton);
    firstButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            bookIndex = 0;
            prepareDisplay(inventoryBook[bookIndex], textArea);
        }
    });

    JButton previousButton = new JButton("Previous");
    buttonPanel.add(previousButton);
    previousButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            bookIndex = bookIndex - 1;
            prepareDisplay(inventoryBook[bookIndex], textArea);
        }
    });

    JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");
    buttonPanel.add(nextButton);
    nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            bookIndex = bookIndex + 1;
            prepareDisplay(inventoryBook[bookIndex], textArea);
        }
    });

    JButton lastButton = new JButton("Last");
    buttonPanel.add(lastButton);
    lastButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {   
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            bookIndex = (inventoryBook.length - 1);
            prepareDisplay(inventoryBook[bookIndex], textArea);
        }
    });
```

Comment: what error do you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `actionPerformed` for the `previousButton` and `nextButton` you need to check what the current `bookIndex` is before you decrement or increment, respectively. In the case of `previousButton`, if the current `bookIndex == 0`, set the bookIndex to `inventoryBook.length-1` instead of decrementing. For the `nextButton`, if the `bookIndex == inventoryBook.length-1`, set `bookIndex` to `0` instead of incrementing. So for `nextButton`:

```
        JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");
        buttonPanel.add(nextButton);
        nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if(bookIndex == inventoryBook.length - 1) {
                    bookIndex = 0;
                } else {
                    bookIndex = bookIndex + 1;
                }

                prepareDisplay(inventoryBook[bookIndex], textArea);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have an out index range in the end on the next button, check the index in

```
JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");
    buttonPanel.add(nextButton);
    nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            // i guess that here is the problem
            bookIndex = bookIndex + 1;
            prepareDisplay(inventoryBook[bookIndex], textArea);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`%` [Modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is the key. It will make the desired cycle simulation.

This will make `next` work as a cycle, that means when you will use `next` at the last index it will take you to the start. Same goes for `prev` just change it for `bookIndex-1`

```
JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");
buttonPanel.add(nextButton);
nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        bookIndex = (bookIndex+1)%inventoryBook.length;
        prepareDisplay(inventoryBook[bookIndex], textArea);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add some bounds checking to make sure previous doesn't go below 0, and next doesn't make it go above the length.